# Как реализовать в своем проекте composer корневые файлы вне папки vendor?

Tags: composer

Разрабатываю библиотеку (микрофреймворк). Решил завезти управление миграциями. Для этого у меня в корневой папке проекта `/var/www/project/` есть файл `sql-migration`, который выполняет определенную логику. К нему идет обращение через консоль. `php sql-migration create [NAME]`.

Как я понял, если мы делаем проект, который хотим поместить в **packagist.org**, то он при инициализации в другом месте поместиться в папку `vendor/developername/project/`. А как мне сделать, чтобы корневые элементы (ядро проекта) было в `vendor`, а файл `sql-migration` в корне папки инициализации? Например, как это реализовано в **Yii**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, решение достаточно простое. Необходимо было создать 2 репозитория: ядро и скелет. Ниже я приведу composer.json обоих проектов, которые были выложены на packagist.org.

Ядро:

```
{
    "name": "kernel",
    "description": "",
    "license": "",
    "keywords": [
        "",
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|^8.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "kernel\\": "kernel"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Скелет:

```
{
    "name": "mepihindeveloper/skinny-php-skeleton",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "",
    "license": "",
    "keywords": [
        "",
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
        "userName/kernel": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "kernel\\": "kernel"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Как видите, тут скрыта некоторая информация, но вся суть в том, что ядро имеет тип `type` по-молчанию и является библиотекой. А скелет проекта имеет `type` **project**. В зависимостях было указано ядро и его версия.

Запуске всего чуда была таким: `composer create-project ТУТ_СКЕЛЕТ ИМЯ_ПРОЕКТА`. `create-project` выполняет как pull, так и install всех зависимостей сразу.